# Assigning String Data to a Varaible

Tags: c#, string, variables

I'm new to programming in general, but I've thoroughly searched this and can't find anything that is related to this, but I admit it may be because I don't know 100% what to look for. So I apologize if this is redundant or extremely simple.

I'm working on an assignment in C# where we have to create a sentinel loop asking for a product # and quantity. With that, we make a calculation for cost and write all of that information to a private string variable.

In order to avoid academic dishonesty, I'll just ask about some code slightly different than the example.

```
 private string test1;

 public string Test1
    {
        get
        {
            return test1;
        }
        set
        {
            test1 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
int number1 Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int number2 = (number1*3);
```

This is the part that I can't figure out. I've tried it several ways:

```
test1 = ("{0}, {1}", number1, number2);
```

and

```
test = ("{0}, {1}", "number1", "number2");
```

as well as both of those iterations without parenthesis.  I also can't get it to work even when "numer1" and "number2" are string variables.

Is it possible to assign this type of string data to a variable?

Comment: `String.Format("{0}, {1}", number1, numbe2);`

Comment: For the sake of argument, try this: `test = String.Format("{0}, {1}", number1, number2);`

Comment: `test = String.Format("{0}, {1}", number1, number2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you edited, the reason your code isn't working is because your not calling `String.Format`.  You can often ignore `String.Format` when you utilize a `Console.WriteLine` which has the functionality built into it.

Which is where I believe your confusion is occurring. To resolve your issue:

```
public class Example
{
     private string example;
     public Example(string example)
     {
         this.example = example;
     }

     public string Demo
     {
          get { return example; }
          private set { example = value; }
     }
}
```

The following class should be straight forward, we have our `parameter` which will assign a value to our `Demo` through the Constructor.  So to store our value, as a `String` we would do the following:

```
var total = 0;
var number = 0;
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number)
     total = number * 3;

var example = new Example(String.Format("{0}, {1}", number, total));
Console.WriteLine(example.Demo);
```

So, the `TryParse` won't throw an exception if it fails to convert the user input.  Then to format the `String` we utilize the `String.Format`.  Then you can see such output by calling `example.Demo`.

Hopefully this clarifies your problem a bit.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I edited it to fix my "code" format... I had left some plain text. Thank you SO much!